# Error in plugin "gulp-sass" when deploy Liferay 7.4 theme

Tags: gulp, liferay, gulp-sass, liferay-theme, liferay-7.4

While migrating my Liferay 7 theme to 7.4 version, I got warnings like

> Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
>
> Recommendation: math.div($spacer, 2) or calc($spacer / 2)

In-order to fix those warnings, I updated my package.json by adding

> "liferayTheme": {         "baseTheme": "styled",      "templateLanguage":
> "ftl",        "version": "7.4",       **"sassOptions": {          "dartSass": false
> }**     }

but after updating this, I did npm install and gulp deploy, it throws the below error
[image]

I tried deleting node-modules/package-lock.json file and updated gulpfile.js by adding and installing through npm

> const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

I also tried the suggestion [here](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/11986134363149-Error-in-plugin-sass-when-migrating-themes-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-Dart-Sass-2-0-0-), but nothing works.

I am running

> node v16.13.0 (npm v8.1.0) (Can't downgrade as this is recommended for
> 7.4)
>
> Gulp 4.0.2
>
> gulp-sass 5.1.0
>
> sass 1.58.0
>
> liferay-theme-tasks 11.4.0

I assume node-sass is deprecated and any pointers in fixing this issue would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

gulp-sass used to have a default compiler which was node-sass.

but as you mentioned, node sass is now deprecated,
insted of node-sass you need to use [dart-sass(sass)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)

and you can use it like this =>

```
const sass = require("gulp-sass")(require("sass"));
```

npm packages that you need =>

```
"gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
"sass": "^1.54.9"
```

- another thing, you might want to migrate to the new ES6-module-gulp-file.
- also you might like this [gulp-boilerplate](https://github.com/Mohamed-Talaat333/gulp-boilerplate)